# PHP - Converting a UTF-8 string to \x escaped form

Tags: php, utf-8

My files contain UTF-8. I want to convert UTF-8 characters in the text to \x sequences and preserve everything else.

For example, the text

```
# Printing 'naïve' and '男孩' with newlines and tabs
    print 'naïve\n'
    print '\t男孩'
```

should be converted to

```
# Printing 'na\xc3\xafve' and '\xe7\x94\xb7\xe5\xad\xa9' with newlines and tabs
    print 'na\xc3\xafve\n'
    print '\t\xe7\x94\xb7\xe5\xad\xa9'
```

I tried the following approach:

```
mb_convert_encoding($text, "UTF-8", "ASCII");
```

This resulted in

```
# Printing 'naÃ¯ve' and 'ç·å­©' with newlines and tabs
    print 'naÃ¯ve\n'
    print '\tç·å­©'
```

(not quite what I was looking for)

I also tried:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII", $text);
```

This resulted in the error:

```
PHP Notice:  iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
```

How do I get around this?